# How to get exact line number and file name from command 'info frame' in tcl if the type is proc or eval?

Tags: tcl

As per Tcl manual,some of the information obtained by executing command "info frame" is:

line ::
This entry provides the number of the line the command is at inside of the script it is a part of. This information is not present for type precompiled. **For type source this information is counted relative to the beginning of the file, whereas for the last two types the line is counted relative to the start of the script.**
file :: 
**This entry is present only for type source**. It provides the normalized path of the file the command is in.

This suggests that the file name and the exact line number cannot be obtained if type is not source,but I need to access exactly these two.Can anyone help me please here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Tcl has the information about what file the script was in (as reported in the `file` and `line` keys returned by `info frame`) then you know where it came from. If Tcl lacks the information — which is possible for a bunch of reasons, such as if the code was automatically generated or if you're doing particularly “clever” code generation — then it *really* can't tell you. The script provenance tracking mechanism is unfortunately rather fragile, as it depends on tracking exact references to string literals at the pointer level to work; when it loses track, it just cannot work it out. (Also, it doesn't use the information it has in error reporting. That's ever so frustrating for me as it would otherwise be the single most important use case!)

Since you can't get perfect tracking in all cases, it's going to be more of a case of seeing whether it is possible to make things work in your *actual* case; that's often rather more possible than you appear to fear. The trick is to capture the information at a point where you've actually normally got it, and to use it appropriately after that. It's not incredibly difficult, but doing it well is among the more complicated parts of code generation in Tcl (unless you write everything out to a file and don't bother tracking beyond that, of course).

Comment: Thanks for ur reply sir.but I am still struggling to find a solution.I am giving you a sample of the code i am working on and its o/p.Any leads will be appreciable

Comment: Code :
proc stacktrace {} {
    set level [info frame];
    ince level -2;
    if {$level > 1} {
        echo Error occured in;
        while {$level} {
            set error_info [info frame $level] ;
            puts "$error_info"
            incr level -1 ;
        }
    }
}

Result:
type proc line 3 cmd {method1} proc ::procA level 1
type eval line 1 cmd {procA 0 { . }} level 2

Comment: Can any command other than info frame or info level be used to achieve this ? this looks a very basic functionality that I can't believe is not available in tcl.

Comment: The *only* command that has the information is `info frame`. It looks like your code is doing something tricky too: I get output from `stackframe` like this: `type source line 18 file /tmp/stackframeexample.tcl cmd {grill $q $r $p} proc ::bar level 2` and that seems perfectly OK to me…

Comment: Sir as per https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/interp.htm#M13,
"interp debug path ?-frame ?bool??" should do the job,but its still not working fr me.I am using the syntax "interp debug {} -frame 1".Is there something wrong in what i am doing ? Please do help me sir.